# Finding expected value of conditional probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we throw a fair dice, and let $X$ be the random variable representing each face (each result: $1,2,3,4,5,6$).
Suppose that we drew $k$ on the dice; we then flip a fair coin $k$ times.
let $Y$ be the random variable representing how many times we drew $H$ (head).
Now, I need to calculate $E(Y|X=3)$, and $E(Y)$.

My answer to the first:
The random variable $Z=(Y|X=3)$ distribution is:

$\mathbb{P}_Z(z=0)=\mathbb{P}_Z(\left\{TTT\right\})=\frac{1}{8}$
$\mathbb{P}_Z(z=1)=\mathbb{P}_Z(\left\{HTT,THT,TTH\right\})=\frac{3}{8}$
$\mathbb{P}_Z(z=2)=\mathbb{P}_Z(\left\{HHT,HTH,THH\right\})=\frac{3}{8}$
$\mathbb{P}_Z(z=3)=\mathbb{P}_Z(\left\{HHH\right\})=\frac{1}{8}$

So finding $E(Z)$ is easy.
But I have no idea how to find $E(Y)$, beacuse I am not really sure how the joint distribution table looks like for $X$ and $Y$ - it's dimensions depends on the $X=x$ value.  meaning, for every $x\in X$, $Y$ gets different possible values!
for example, what would be $\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(X=2,Y=6)$?  we don't know, because we throw the coin only two times!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what you told us, it seems $P(X=2,Y=6)=0$. One way of finding $E[Y]$ is finding $E[Y|X=k]$ for each $k$ and then applying $E[Y] = \sum_{k=1}^{6}{E[Y|X=k]P(X=k)}$.

Comment: Beware that "The random variable Z=(Y|X=3)" is a nonexistent object.

Comment: @Did, what's wrong with Z? why is it nonexistent?

Comment: Because the notion is in no (decent) textbook. How would you define it?

Comment: This notion came from my instructor, if I remember right.
How is it different from any other random variable? It has values, and each has a probability. in this sense, it forms a valid distribution.

Comment: "it forms a valid distribution" Not at all, actually... "How is it different from any other random variable?" How does your instructor suggest to define this random variable on Omega?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry... I was confusing $E(Y|X=3)$ with $E(Y|X)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the probability of head is the same as the probability of tail, $E(Y|X=3)=3-E(Y|X=3)$ which gives $E(Y|X=3)=1.5$. Thus, $E(Y)=\sum_{j=1}^6 E(Y|X=j)/6 =\sum_{j=1}^6 (j/2)/6 = 6 \times (6+1) /24 = 42/24=7/4$.

Answer (score 1):

One can do the calculation "from basics," but there are faster ways.

Given that $X=k$, the random variable $Y$ has *binomial distribution*, $k$ trials, probability of success $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $E(Y|X=k)=\frac{k}{2}$.

Then $E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{6}{2}\right)=\frac{7}{4}$.

**Remark:** The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ can be written down.  The probability that $X=k$ and $Y=y$ is $\frac{1}{6}\binom{k}{y}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^y$. Then we can use the table directly to find $E(Y)$, or first use the table to write down the distribution of $Y$, and then $E(Y)$. That is less efficient than working directly with expectations.

Comment: You've swapped an $X$ and $Y$ there.

Comment: Look at the sentence that begins with the word "Thus".